# spacing between two points in 3d cordinate system

Tags: vb.net

i am a bit new to this but I'm trying to create a randomly generated 3d coordinate points with equal spacing, I've tried using for each loop but im confused on how to use in. the purpose is to generate sphere around that point but some sphere are overlapping each other. thanks in advance. the code below is to show how I'm generating the sphere

```
    For i = 0 To noofsp - 1
        x = Rnd(1) * maxDist
        ws1.Cells(i + 5, 2) = x

        y = Rnd(1) * maxDist
        ws1.Cells(i + 5, 3) = y

        z = Rnd(1) * maxDist
        ws1.Cells(i + 5, 4) = z

        centers.Add({x, y, z})
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to check the new point against all the other points to make sure that your new point is at a greater distance that the sum of the radii of your new sphere and each sphere you're checking against

You'll need to use pythagoras' theorem to check that the distances and I found the code below from [this site](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/365641-Calculate-the-Distance-between-two-2D-or-3D-points./). The code on the site is written in c#, but here is the vb.net version.

```
Public Function Distance3D(x1 As Double, y1 As Double, z1 As Double, x2 As Double, y2 As Double, z2 As Double) As Double
    '     __________________________________
    'd = √ (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2
    '
    'Our end result
    Dim result As Double
    'Take x2-x1, then square it
    Dim part1 As Double = Math.Pow((x2 - x1), 2)
    'Take y2-y1, then square it
    Dim part2 As Double = Math.Pow((y2 - y1), 2)
    'Take z2-z1, then square it
    Dim part3 As Double = Math.Pow((z2 - z1), 2)
    'Add both of the parts together
    Dim underRadical As Double = part1 + part2 + part3
    'Get the square root of the parts
    result = Math.Sqrt(underRadical)
    'Return our result
    Return result
End Function
```

To generate the spheres, you would need to expand your code to include checking the new point against all the previously generated points. That code is below with comments.

I have assumed the definition of a variable called `minDistance` to specify how far apart the centre of the spheres should be. I'm also assuming that all the spheres are the same size. The number should be twice the radius of the spheres

```
Private Sub GenerateSpheres()
    Randomize
    For i As Integer = 0 To noofsp - 1
        Dim distanceOK As Boolean = False
        Dim x, y, z As Integer
        'keep generating points until one is found that is
        'far enough away. When it is, add it to your data

        While distanceOK = False

            x = Rnd(1) * maxDist
            y = Rnd(1) * maxDist
            z = Rnd(1) * maxDist
            'If no other points have been generated yet, don't bother
            'checking your new point
            If centers.Count = 0 Then
                distanceOK = True
            Else
                'If other points exist, loop through the list and check distance
                For j As Integer = 0 To centers.Count - 1
                    'if the point is too close to any other, stop checking,
                    'exit the For Loop and the While Loop will generate a new
                    'coordinate for checking, and so on
                    Dim dist As Integer = Distance3D(centers(j)(0), centers(j)(1), centers(j)(2), x, y, z)
                    If dist <= minDistance Then
                        distanceOK = False
                        'exit the For loop and start the next iteration of the While Loop
                        Continue While
                    End If
                Next
                'If all previous points have been checked none are too close
                'flag distanceOK as true
                distanceOK = True
            End If
        End While
        'ws1.Cells(i + 5, 2) = x
        'ws1.Cells(i + 5, 3) = y
        'ws1.Cells(i + 5, 4) = z
        centers.Add({x, y, z})
    Next
End Sub
```